# Spigot - Player#sendBlockChange не работает

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit-api

Используется Paper 1.12.2 в качестве ядра, Spigot 1.12.2 в качестве API.

Эффекта почему-то нет совсем никакого. Выводить все переменные в консоль уже пробовала, всё верно.

Цель: заменить блоки из списка на другой тип, но только для определённого игрока.

```
        // p - Player / игрок онлайн
        // s - List<Block> / список блоков, находящихся в поле зрения игрока

        Material material = Material.getMaterial(Settings.FREEZE_STRING_BLOCK());
        if (material == null) {
            LogManager.log(LogType.ERROR, "Freeze block material not found! Setting as COBBLESTONE...");
            material = Material.COBBLESTONE;
        }

        Material finalMaterial = material;
        s.forEach(block -> p.sendBlockChange(block.getLocation(), finalMaterial, (byte) finalMaterial.getId() /* 0 или 1 также не дают эффекта*/));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ: Нужно обновлять вид блоков с интервалом, например, с помощью

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer
```